# Rule of four ? Calculate number given other 5

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a pair of values x y  ( 4 numbers, not 3 ) e.g. 
 x  -> y 
-------- 
29 -> 20 
15 -> 100

How can I calculate a middle value e.g.  
21 ->  ?   
given the min and max values of each columns x and y

what I'm looking is for the sequence but only knowing 2 pairs

following this example, the list of number could be   
23 -> approx 40  
21 -> approx 60  
18 -> approx 80 
etc 

is possible to extrapolate the sequence ?

thanks!!

Was solved by Ross!,  thanks a lot

29 -> 20 
28 -> 25.714285714286 
27 -> 31.428571428571
26 -> 37.142857142857
25 -> 42.857142857143
24 -> 48.571428571429
23 -> 54.285714285714
22 -> 60
21 -> 65.714285714286
20 -> 71.428571428571
19 -> 77.142857142857
18 -> 82.857142857143
17 -> 88.571428571429
16 -> 94.285714285714
15 -> 100

Comment: This is not at all clear.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to find a function that relates the $x$ values to the $y$ values.  But even then, there is not enough information to even begin.  Might as well say $21\to 19$ because, why not!

Comment: Sorry,   I will add something more

Comment: As it stands, this really makes no sense.  Are there any conditions at all on the association?  If I said $21\to 1003$ how would you know that was wrong?

Comment: because the number should be between to min and max of the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly view your data as two points on a line and use the [two-point form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) for a line to compute any other points.  That is 
$$y-100=\frac {20-100}{29-15}(x-15)$$
Plugging in $x=21$ gives $y=65\frac 57$

Comment: Thanks a lot!,  you are a genius !!!

Answer (score 0):

29 -> 20 
15 -> 100

y=mx+b

m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

m=(100-20)/(15-29)=80/-14=-5.714...

if x = 0 what is y?

y=(80/-14)*x+b

y=100

x=15

100=(80/-14)*15+b

b=100/((80/-14)*15)=-1.166

y=(80/-14)*x-1.166

https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-1/formulating-linear-equations/writing-linear-equations-using-the-slope-intercept-form